# Local file existence condition in bash FTP script

Tags: bash, scripting, ftp, local

I want to get a file from a server conditional on the non-existence of the file in the local directory. In the final script there will be many files but here is an example just using one.

I'm trying this:

```
#!/bin/bash
HOST='a.b.c.d'
USER='anonymous'
PASSWD='pass'

ftp -n -v $HOST << EOT
user $USER $PASSWD
prompt
binary

!test -f filename && get /remotedir/remotefilename filename

bye
EOT
```

I get this error: `+bash: get: command not found`, presumably because `get` is called in the local rather than the in the FTP but I don't know how to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Replace

```
!test -f filename && get /remotedir/remotefilename filename
```

by

```
$(test -f filename && echo get /remotedir/remotefilename filename)
```

Comment: Great. That works perfectly. `$(test ! -f filename && echo get /remotedir/remotefilename filename)` is the solution. I missed out a ! in my original example to test for non-existence. Thanks.